# how application object is shared to users

Tags: asp.net, object

Can you please give a brief details on how application object is shared to users.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I was asked in an Interview how every user who are accessing the web application gets updated application objects.

Comment: Are you talking about the ASP Application object or the ASP.NET HttpApplication class? And what do you mean by "shared to users"?

Comment: I need to know how and why it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application state is a data repository available to all classes in an ASP.NET application. This repository is stored in memory on the web server. Unlike session state, which is specific to a single user session, application state applies to all users and sessions.

As to how it's stored, that's in an instance of the HttpApplicationState class. This class exposes a key-value dictionary of objects, and an instance of this class is created the first time a user accesses any URL resource in the web application.

The most common way for a developer to access this stored state is through the Application property of the HttpContext class.